# Как вызвать название переменной в #define?

Tags: c++, препроцессор

```
#define trace(x) cout << "x=" << x;
```

Я хочу чтобы при вызове

```
int a = 5;
trace(a)
```

вывод был `a=5`.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот так:

```
#define trace(x) cout << #x "=" << x;
```

Здесь `#x` раскрывается в `"a"`.

Между `#x` и `"="` можно не ставить `<<`, так как стоящие рядом строковые литералы автоматически объединяются в один.